# What does this mean? (int &)a

Tags: c++

define a float variable a, convert a to float & and int &, what does this mean? After the converting , a is a reference of itself? And why the two result is different?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int
main(void)
{
    float a = 1.0;
    cout << (float &)a <<endl;
    cout << (int &)a << endl;

    return 0;
}


thinkpad ~ # ./a.out 
1
1065353216
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cout << (float &)a <<endl;
cout << (int &)a << endl;
```

The first one treats the bits in a like it's a float.  The second one treats the bits in a like it's an int.  The bits for float 1.0 just happen to be the bits for integer 1065353216.

It's basically the equivalent of:

```
float a = 1.0;
int* b = (int*) &a;
cout << a << endl;
cout << *b << endl;
```

`(int &) a` casts a to a reference to an integer.  In other words, an integer reference to a.  (Which, as I said, treats the contents of a as an integer.)

Edit: I'm looking around now to see if this is valid.  I suspect that it's not.  It's depends on the type being less than or equal to the actual size.

Comment: That's interesting.  I did not know that casting to a reference type was effectively equivalent to performing a reinterpret cast.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I can't tell if you're being serious or sarcastic, so please elaborate if you're not being serious.  (I'm not sure if this is valid or not.  Before now, I've never seen a cast to a reference to an unrelated type.  I'm trying to search around for anything from the standard but am not having much luck.)  Edit: To clarify a bit, in my post, I'm explaining what is happening, not what is guaranteed to happen.  I suppose I should clarify that in the answer.

Comment: now, the first part i have understand. but the seconde part , (int &)a, i am a littel confused , because when we define a reference , we must initialize the reference , right ? like int &a = b; but this case , how to explain? (int &) a is now a integer reference , but we don't know the variable that it refers ?

Comment: It is valid, but what happens is implementation defined (the same as for the reinterpret_cast)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It may or may not be, depending on the source and the target type.  Casting a object to a reference type is the same as casting the address of the object to a pointer type, then dereferencing the results.

Comment: @ccsnailpp `(int&) a` references a while treating it as an int.  Basically the program then interprets the bits stored in a as if a were an int.

Comment: @VJovic It's undefined behavior according to the standard.  The intent is clearly that it behave in a manner corresponding to what someone familiar with the low level architecture of the machine would expect, but there's no way the standard can specify this, so it's left as undefined behavior in the standard.  (An implementation is free to define any undefined behavior it wants.)

Comment: @Corbin: I'm not being sarcastic; I genuinely didn't know one could do this.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah ok.  I thought you were hinting that it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Downvoter way after the fact care to explain?  With no proper citations, and basically saying what *is* happening and not what is guaranteed to happen, I understand; I'm just curious what in particular it was.

Answer (score 9):

It means undefined behavior:-).

Seriously, it is a form of type punning.  `a` is a `float`, but `a` is also a block of memory (typically four bytes) with bits in it.  `(float&)a` means to treat that block of memory as if it were a `float` (in other words, what it actually is); `(int&)a` means to treat it as an `int`.  Formally, accessing an object (such as `a`) through an lvalue expression with a type other than the actual type of the object is undefined behavior, unless the type is a character type.  Practically, if the two types have the same size, I would expect the results to be a reinterpretation of the bit pattern.

In the case of a `float`, the bit pattern contains bits for the sign, an exponent and a mantissa.  *Typically*, the exponent will use some excess-n notation, and only `0.0` will have 0 as an exponent.  (Some representations, including the one used on PCs, will not store the high order bit of the mantissa, since in a normalized form in base 2, it must always be 1.  In such cases, the stored mantissa for `1.0` will have all bits 0.)  Also typically (and I don't know of any exceptions here), the exponent will be stored in the high order bits.  The result is when you "type pun" a floating point value to a an integer of the same size, the value will be fairly large, regardless of the floating point value.

Comment: But the same stands for reinterpret_cast, therefore what happens is implementation defined. Or, am I wrong?

Comment: @VJovic In this case, it is a `reinterpret_cast`.  The conversion itself is more or less well defined (providing no alignment constraints are violated).  Using the results of the conversion are formally undefined behavior (but the intent is that they do what someone familiar with the underlying architecture would expect).

Answer (score 2):

The values are different because interpreting a `float` as an `int &` (reference to `int`) throws the doors wide open. `a` is not an `int`, so pretty much anything could actually happen when you do that. As it happens, looking at that `float` like it's an `int` gives you `1065353216`, but depending on the underlying machine architecture it could be `42` or an elephant in a pink tutu or even crash.

Note that this is not the same as casting to an `int`, which understands how to convert from `float` to `int`. Casting to `int &` just looks at bits in memory without understanding what the original meaning is.

Comment: Are you saying that this is undefined behaviour, or merely implementation-defined?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't know what he's saying, but the standard clearly says it is undefined behavior.  (The standard also makes it fairly clear that the intent is that an implementation do what someone familiar with the architecture of the machine would expect.  Which on some architectures could mean crashing for certain floating point values.  (I've never heard of an architecture where I'd expect an elephant in a pink tutu, however.)

Comment: I mean it's undefined behaviour, yes. The elephant in a pink tutu is unlikely, but is permitted by the standard...